# php regex para obter 2 grupos de link href

Tags: php, regex

Olá, como montar uma REGEX para obter 2 grupos de todos os link href

```
<a href="/page/page/categoria/page?page=2&amp;publica=1" rel="next">2</a>
```

Onde o grupo 1 seria todo o link

```
/page/page/categoria/page?page=2&amp;publica=1
```

E o segundo grupo seria o número da página (page=**?**)

```
2
```

Minha REGEX por em quanto ta assim:

```
href=["][^"]+page=(\d+).+["]
// GRUPO 1: href="/page/page/categoria/page?page=2&amp;publica=1" rel="next"
// GRUPO 2: 2
```

Comment: Se entendi o unico problema da sua regex e que ela esta retornando o ` `rel="next"` junto?

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a minha resposta lhe ajudou? Se não, informe poderia teve alguma duvida no uso dela.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de regex você pode usar [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), uma API do PHP que trabalha com XML e HTML, um exemplo seria assim:

```
$conteudoDoHtml = '<a href="/page/page/categoria/page?page=2&amp;publica=1" rel="next">2</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($conteudoDoHtml);
$ancoras = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($ancoras as $elementos) {
   echo $elementos->getAttribute('href'), '<hr>';
}
```

Então você faria apenas uma regex pra extrair o `page`

```
$conteudoDoHtml = '<a href="/page/page/categoria/page?page=2&amp;publica=1" rel="next">2</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($conteudoDoHtml);
$ancoras = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($ancoras as $elementos) {
   $data = $elementos->getAttribute('href');

   echo 'Conteudo de href:', $data, '<br>';

   preg_match('#(&amp;|&|\?)page=(\d+)#', $data, $match);

   echo 'page=', $data[2], '<br>';

   var_dump($match);//Pra visualizar melhor o resultado do preg_match
   echo '<hr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
href="([^"]+\?(page=([^&]*))[^"]+)"
```

Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lZ1lZ8/1)

Basicamente, ela captura o href que contenha page. E subdivide do modo que você quer.

```
match[1] = toda url
match[2] = page=conteudo
match[3] = conteudo
```