# Buscar string dentro de uma tag php

Tags: php, regex

Ao usar em vários tipos de embed de vários sites, e ir buscar apenas o link. Por exemplo:

Youtube: `<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HLhuNbO0egU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Vimeo: `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143592640?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`

O que eu quero, é ficar apenas com o link do vídeo, ou seja, o que está dentro do src="". No caso do youtube fico com https://www.youtube.com/embed/HLhuNbO0egU

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/php-regex-para-obter-2-grupos-de-link-href

Comment: Você esta fazendo isso direto no navegados ou é uma captura de `SOAP`, `CURL` do php mesmo?

Comment: dentro do navegador, o embed vem da base de dados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que podes fazer é um `preg_match` da `tag` com uma expressão regular:

```
    $link_to_getURL= '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HLhuNbO0egU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $array = array();
    preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $link_to_getURL, $array ) ;
    print_r($array[1]);    //link saida
```

O link completo vai sair na `$array`

Answer (score 1):

#### Em JavaScript :

```
var arraySrc = new Array();
jQuery('iframe').each(function(){
    var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    arraySrc.push(src);
});
```

#### Em PHP :

```
$strHtml = <<<EOD
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HLhuNbO0egU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143592640?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
EOD;

preg_match_all('~<(iframe).*src="([^"]+)".*></\1>~', $strHtml, $match);

$arraySrc = array();
foreach($match[2] as $k => $value){
    $arraySrc[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: O que é esse `<<<EOD`?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Interessante, não conhecia esse recurso ainda.